# How to determine the most frequently visited routes through a web site by visitors?

Tags: statistics, usage-statistics, visitor-statistic

I want to be able to discover the 10 most popular routes through our web site that lead a visitor to register with us.

I have already logged all of this info, but don't seem to be able to find the best solution to query it.

The site is quite high traffic, > 3 million page views per month, so the solution needs to scale.

What suggestions do people have for how I could implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very difficult problem. I finally solved it using neo4j.